# When using vite to start, the introduction of 5M file in public, resulting in startup loading more than 20 seconds, what is the solution?

Tags: vue.js, static, vite

I built a project with vite. There is a 5m js file in public that needs to be introduced in index.html, which causes ('npm run dev') a long startup or reload time of around 20 seconds.

So what's the solution?

thank you

1. Can the introduction of CDNS reduce time?
2. Or when entering a page, in loading the js file is also OK?

Comment: I mean, 5 millions files is a hell of an amount of files. It's obviously time consuming while bundling, and also will be hard for the browser to load.
A CDN reduces download time and provide worldwild replication but won't help in terms of bundling / parsing the scripts by the browser.

Comment: @Kapcash Thanks for your reply!
It doesn't matter how long the browser takes to load, but is there a way to run "npm run dev" with a shorter startup time?

Comment: Maybe, but this is out of my skills set. You could try to ask this on the vite github discussions panel or in their Discord server, so a Vite expert could answer you :)